# plotting scatters with multiple colors depending on a value

Tags: python, plotly

I have the following script

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import pandas as pd

# Sample data for the first subplot
x1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y1 = [10, 12, 5, 8, 6]

# Sample data for the second subplot
x2 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y2 = [3, 7, 11, 8, 12]

# Create DataFrames with the data and indices for both subplots
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'X-axis': x1, 'Y-axis': y1, 'Index': range(len(x1))})
data2 = pd.DataFrame({'X-axis': x2, 'Y-axis': y2, 'Index': range(len(x2))})

# Create subplots with shared y-axes
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, subplot_titles=('Subplot 1', 'Subplot 2'), shared_yaxes=True)

# Add traces for the first subplot
trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=data1['X-axis'],
    y=data1['Y-axis'],
    mode='markers',
    text=data1['Index'],
    hovertemplate='Index: %{text}',
    name='Subplot 1'
)
fig.add_trace(trace1, row=1, col=1)

# Add traces for the second subplot
trace2 = go.Scatter(
    x=data2['X-axis'],
    y=data2['Y-axis'],
    mode='markers',
    text=data2['Index'],
    hovertemplate='Index: %{text}',
    name='Subplot 2'
)
fig.add_trace(trace2, row=1, col=2)


# Update layout
fig.update_layout(title_text='Two Scatter Subplots Side by Side', showlegend=True)

# Manually add Y-axis titles
fig.update_yaxes(title_text='Y-axis', row=1, col=1)

# Show the figure
fig.show()
```

When run, I can have the following plot

[image]

Very nice.(well I would have preferred both subplots of the same color but...)

How ever I would like to modify this plot with the following:

This time I will add a column to the data like

```
data1['marked']=['a','','b','','c']
data2['marked']=['b','c','','a','']
```

and based on this value (empty or a string) color the dots in the plot.

How can I do this?

P.S.
I have thought of filtering the dataframe for each value and plotting each separately but this seems overwork for something that I guess should be simpler.
I got this

[image]

which yes got the job done, but is this really that complicated?

Comment: To sum up, if you want the legend for the second graph in the question, you need a loop process. If you do not need a legend, create a dictionary of colors corresponding to the marked column values. Set that dictionary to the marker color. `color_dict = {'a':'red','b':'green','c':'blue','':'black'};trace1 = go.Scatter(...,marker=dict(color=data1['marked'].map(color_dict)),...)` Then hide the legend.